# WSUS SUSDB SQL processes blocking during reset

Tags: sql-server

I've hunted high and low over the years about WSUS and all anyone says is it is slow when doing things like a reset and there's no way to gauge progress, stop it (without the update to singleton data) and so on.

My own WSUS has always had major SQL blocking issues whenever I reset it.

Digging deeper, the SQL server appears to be seriously struggling with process blocking [see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7pxh.png).

When you look at what is causing the blocking, it is a variety of CREATE PROC statements with the ChildEulas one being a major culprit.

So is it that the reason resets are soooooo slow is that the reset is having to drop/re-create the stored procedures for each and every update in the DB and throwing in blocking makes it absolutely ridiculous.

Can we re-write the reset routine to stop it dropping/creating the stored procs and make it lightning fast?

I tried killing the blocking process whenever it was a create proc statement (as the proc was already actually still there, presumably in a transaction) but it keeps halting the WSUS service altogether.

Comment: Make sure when you include an image you add a `!` in front of the link so `![text](<img link>)`

Comment: OK and thanks for the tip but it's telling me I need 10 rep pts to do that.